# Setting multiple field to awk variables at once

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to set an awk variable field to several field at once.

Right now I can only set the variables one by one.

```
for line in `cat file.txt`;do
    var1=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    var2=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    var3=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $3}'`

    #Some complex code....
done
```

I think this is costly cause it parses the linux variable several times. Is there a special syntax to set the variable at once? I know that awk has a BEGIN and END block but the reason I am trying to avoid the BEGIN and END block is to avoid nested awk.

I plan to place another loop and awk code in the #Some complex code.... part.

```
for line in `cat file.txt`;do
    var1=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    var2=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    var3=`echo $line | awk -F, '{print $3}'`

    for line2 in `cat file_old.txt`;do
        vara=`echo $line2 | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
        varb=`echo $line2 | awk -F, '{print $2}'`

        # Do comparison of $var1,var2 and $vara,$varb , then do something with either
    done
done
```

Comment: Why not using `awk` for the comparison and 'doing something'?

Comment: Can you give a sample code on using two file compared with awk? note that the two files file.txt and file_old.txt can have different line size.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted to compare them with eachother. Depends on the specific problem you are trying to solve and the structure of the files, but I have the strong impression that we there are nicer solutions.

Comment: Yes, this definitely sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `IFS` internal field separator to use a comma (instead of whitespace) and do the assignments in a `while` loop:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS;
IFS=',';
while read line; do
    set -- $line;
    var1=$1;
    var2=$2;
    var3=$3;
    ...
done < file.txt

IFS=$SAVEIFS;
```

This will save a copy of your current `IFS`, change it to a `,` character, and then iterate over each line in your file. The line `set -- $line;` will convert each word (separated by a comma) into a numeric-variable (`$1`, `$2`, etc.). You can either use these variables directly, or assign them to other (more meaningful) variable names.

Alternatively, you could use `IFS` with the answer provided by William:

```
IFS=',';
while read var1 var2 var3; do
    ...
done < file.txt
```

They are functionally identical and it just comes down to whether or not you want to explicitly set `var1=$1` or have it defined in the `while`-loop's head.

Comment: Is there any problem when nesting two while loop? Would the variable $1 $2 $3 have an effect?

Comment: If you call `set -- $variable;` again inside a nested loop, the `$1`, `$2`, .., `$n` variables that are set will be overridden in the parent-loop as well. So, if you want to use that method, you may want to make sure you assign them to other variables first.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `awk` at all?

```
while IFS=, read var1 var2 var3; do
  ...
done < file.txt
```

Comment: If the data is comma-separated, the same approach would work with the input field seperator set to ','.  Add `IFS=','` before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash    
FILE="/tmp/values.txt"

    function parse_csv() { 
    local lines=$lines;
    > $FILE
    OLDIFS=$IFS;
    IFS=","
    i=0
    for val in ${lines}
    do
      i=$((++i))
      eval var${i}="${val}"
    done
    IFS=$OLDIFS;
    for ((j=1;j<=i;++j))
    do
      name="var${j}"
      echo ${!name} >> $FILE
    done

    }

    for lines in `cat file_old.txt`;do
     parse_csv;
    done
```

The problem you have described has only got 3 values, would there be a chance that 3 values may differ and be 4 or 5 or undefined ?

if so the above will parse through the csv line by line and output each value at a time on a new line in a file called /tmp/values.txt

feel free to modify to match your requirements its far more dynamic than defining 3 values